# Kafka consumer reprocessing without transactions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If have a consumer application that reads messages from a partition do some data transformation and store it in an external data store like a database or invoking a rest service, what are the posible patterns or solutions to deal with the reprocessing of messages in case of consumer failure or rebalance?? It's exactly once processing but as i'm  dealing with external services enabling transactions will not help me.

Comment: For every database write, you could do a read to compare what already exists

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that question is not specific to Kafka since it's a general problem of idempotent handling messages. The only thing that is Kafka-related is committing the offset at the right time.

So what are possible approaches?

First of all, in case of writing message's data to a DB it's often pretty straightforward. If you are writing messages to a key-value storage, then it is usually done with a built-in "upsert" operation, which is already idempotent, and will make no difference if applied again with the same data. If you are inserting data into classic RDBMS via SQL, then think of unique field in your data and add a unique constraint in the DB. If it's not yet exists, it could be the message partition+offset in the worst case. In case of message duplicate you can either ignore related SQL error or use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT (unique_field) DO NOTHING` clause.

If working with a rest service, you have to make it methods idempotent somehow. Sometimes it's already OK to call some method twice by accident. Otherwise, you have to add an "idempotency key" to rest calls and handle them in the service implementation. Handling means checking whether message with such idempotency key has already been processed. You can take a concatenation of partition+offset as an idempotency key,

Answer (score 0):

one approach you can take is

1. for every event of kafka maintain a process_count a persistent store
2. During consumption check if for the current event process_count>0 skip processing else process then set process_count=1 and store